# Python unhashable type: slice on list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a little script that will look at a string of text, remove the stop words, then return the top 10 most commonly used words in that string as a list.

This is my code:

```
from collections import Counter as c
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
description = ("This is some place holder text for a shop that sells shoes, coats and jumpers.  We sell lots of shoes but never sell t-shirts.  Please come to our shop if you want some jumpers")
description = ([word for word in description.lower().split() if word not in stop])
common_list = c(description)
top_ten = (common_list[:9])
```

However, this gives me the error message `unhashable type: slice`.  I think this is because common_list might not actually be a list..  I am very new to python so please excuse if this is really silly.

Comment: `from collections import Counter as c` whhhhyyy would you ever do this? Do you hate people being able to read and understand your code?

Comment: And yes, `common_list` is *not a list*, it is a `Counter`, which may have been more obvious if you didn't use `c` instead of `Counter`. A `Counter` object works almost exactly like `dict`, except it is specialized for counting. When you do `my_counter[:9]` that's like doing `my_dict[:9]`, i.e., it passes a *slice* to `__getitem__`, but `dict` objects don't impement slicing...

Comment: And note that of course Counter items have a specific method to get the top n items, namely [`most_common(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So would my answer work...? I can't properly test it but I think it does.

Comment: @JoeIddon yeah, it looks like it would work, but it's not necessary. `Counter` objects have a `most_common` method.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's a really useful method especially for this, I wrote an answer even though you suggested it so that this can be useful to future readers...

Comment: Thanks.  most_common worked, really helpful.  Need to do some more reading into counters.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `Counter` object's `most_common` `method` which makes it really easy:

```
top_ten = c(description).most_common(10)
```

The documentation states:

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least.

So as it returns both the `element` and their `counts` and we only want the `element`, we still need to use a `list-comprehension`:

```
top_ten = [i[0] for i in c(description).most_common(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

common_list is a dictionary, can't slice it (common_list[:9] won't work). You probably have to convert the common_list into an actual list and sort that one based on the occurrences.

Comment: See comments 2 and 3 for a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
top_ten = sorted(c(description).items(), key=lambda p:p[1])[::-1][:10]
```

---

**why?**

Well you essentially have a `list` of words:

```
description = ["cat", "fish", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog"]
```

and then you can get the counts of each elements with the `c()` `function` so by taking `c(description)` which gives:

```
Counter({'cat': 3, 'dog': 2, 'fish': 1})
```

and then we need to sort this and that is done by sorting on the second element of each `tuple` with `key=lambda p:p[1]`. Which in our case would give:

```
[('fish', 1), ('dog', 2), ('cat', 3)]
```

then we need to reverse it with `[::-1]` and take the first `10` elements with `[:10]`. Which would leave us with:

```
[('cat', 3), ('dog', 2), ('fish', 1)]
```

---

If you just want the `words`, just take the first element from each `list` in the `top_ten` list with:

```
[i[0] for i in top_ten]
```

Comment: This can be simplified to: `sorted(c(description).items(), key=lambda p:p[1], reversed=True)[:10]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree, there was an unnecessary `list` conversion, but does this actually have any performance improvements (using `reverse=True`)?

Comment: well, yes. slicing creates a whole new list.